# Creating object for FALSE literal with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am writing a function that returns `BinaryExpression`, which I'm going to pass into `Query.filter()` method. We are using `mypy` in our project so I must specify returning type. It looks like:

```
def get_conditions() -> BinaryExpression:
    return User.name == 'Andrew'
```

But sometimes my function should return `False` condition which will then produce SQL `WHERE False`.

I tried to solve it this way:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import ColumnElement, False_

def get_conditions(forbidden: bool) -> ColumnElement:
    if forbidden:
        return False_

    return User.name == 'Andrew'
```

But I'm getting error when running program:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression for WHERE/HAVING role expected, got <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.False_'>.
```

And I'm getting error when running mypy:

```
 Incompatible return value type (got "Type[False_]", expected "ColumnElement[Any]")
```

What's wrong here? May be I should use type other than `ColumnElement`? I don't want to use expressions like `1=0` because those are magic numbers and it's a bit clumsy

Comment: Right now the problem is your function is returning a `union`. Depending on a condition it's either `BinaryExpression` or a plain `bool`. You can specify union return type by `Union[BinaryExpression, bool]` after importing typing or `BinaryExpression|bool` in newer python.

Comment: How about returning `literal(False)`?

Comment: `from sqlalchemy import false` and then just `return false()` instead of what you have now, should do the trick I guess

Comment: you should call it `False_()`

Comment: Seems that `BinaryExpression` is a bad idea. I looked towards using `ColumnElement` because `BinaryExpression`  and `False_` inherit `ColumnElement` either . But I still get errors. I updated the question

Comment: Yea! `False_()` did the trick

Comment: yeah, I would use `false()` over `False_()`, just my personal preference, feel free to self answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with missing parenthesis after `False_`.

This code worked:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import ColumnElement, False_

def get_conditions(forbidden: bool) -> ColumnElement:
    if forbidden:
        return False_()

    return User.name == 'Andrew'
```

Thanks to [python_user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12502959/python-user)